# clean HDMI output camera - on start

Tags: streaming, hdmi

I am looking for a 4K camcorder or DSLR camera for live streaming (tangential question: is camcorder or DSLR better for that?).
To have live streaming, I need pure HDMI output.  Currently I do it with an old non-4K Canon camcorder and it works well, but if the camera restarts, I need to reconfigure it to have pure HDMI picture. I would like to hook it up in a wifi controlled outlet so that I can turn the camera on remotely and start streaming.  So I need the camera to boot into pure HDMI output w/o me having to mess with the controls.

Comment: [Relevant question on Photo.SE](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/117704/9161)

Answer (score 2):

First: 4k for livestreaming is pretty overkill. Please remember that your streaming device (your computer) and internet upload speed need handle this... AND to top things of not all of your viewers will be able to watch the stream in 4k because of their internet and missing out 4k devices.

[Alpha Gaming](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCATWC1JSlhzmYeDbjnS8WwA) (Harris Heller) is covering everything you want to know about cameras (and livestreaming) in video form on youtube.

Here are the most popular (and very professional but "only" 1080p not 4k) cameras for livestreaming with very helpful information: [a sony should be your choice](https://youtu.be/3GPz5WRKQwU?t=131)

And here are some additional information for you before you choose your camera and lense: [equipment all around your camera](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=efO45WUtmOc)

IMHO, this should be your question: **How much FOV (field of view) and DOF (depth of field) do you want?**

If you really want to live stream in 4k (only 30 fps) then the **SONY A6100** should be a good choice.

Comment: Hi MiTSCHO and welcome to Video.SE! Your answer is very dependent on the video links. If they go down your answer is no longer usefull. It's also not clear what video specifically answers this question. Could you perhaps summarize the conclusion of (one of) the relevant videos?

Comment: Hey Saaru Lindestøkke! I adjusted my answer and specified the videos.

Answer (score 0):

Product-recommendations become out-of-date very quickly, but I would recommend the BMPCC4K. Black magic just came out with the 6k-Version of their pocket cinema camera and thus the price of the 4k variant dropped. All in all, I think that the BMPCC4K is one of the best cameras for this "cheap". You also have a HDMI-out that can be used for livestreaming. I'm assuming you're using something like the elgato usb camlink?

Comment: This is total overkill for live streaming. The smaller Blackmagic cameras would be more fitting.